# jboss 5.1.0 GA slowness in Ubuntu 14.0.4 server

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, jboss

We have developed a java based web application deployed in jboss 5.1.0.GA application server hosted in Ubuntu server.
Same application is hosted in test environment with same servers (Ubuntu and Jboss).
The performance in the Test environment is fine. But in Prod server 16 GB memory(double than test environment) the application is too slow.
With only 1 user, pages loading is taking 3-4 minutes.

Below are few difference in Test and Prod servers:

- DNS is configured in Prod and not in Test
- SSL is configured in Prod and not in Test
- Reverse Proxy is configured in Prod and not in Test
- Prod memory is double than Test

We checked at resource utilization level and there is no issue in that area as well as in network latency.

JVM heap size currently defined:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m –Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

Database is Mysql and is hosted in another Ubuntu server.

When we checked application logs, hibernate queries are taking few minutes to execute in Prod, but in Test it is in few seconds.

In Server.xml, below sections are enabled

We tried swapping the DB servers. When prod DB is connected to Test App server, performance is good. When Test Db is connected to Prod App server, performance is bad.

Please let me know which area to be looked into.